# Suspend systemd watchdog

Tags: systemd

I have a service that is configured with `WatchdogSec=15`. I need to debug it, so I need to temporarily disable the watchdog so it does not get killed while I have it stopped in the debugger.

I tried

```
systemctl set-property app.service WatchdogSec=infinity
```

but I am getting

```
Unknown assignment WatchdogSec=infinity.
```

It is not the `infinity` part; I get the same with `0` or another number.

Is there a(ny other) way to temporarily disable the watchdog?

The target has slightly outdated systemd 232.

Note: there is a suite of several processes tied together with two kinds of IPC, so trying to disable them in systemd and start them manually is not a good idea—the start-up is *complicated*.

Comment: I wonder (haven't tested) if you updated the unit file on-disk and did a daemon-reload; would that update systemd's knowledge on the matter?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, yes, it does. It is still somewhat strange that the `set-property` does not work, plus it would make sense to be able to do it temporarily.